# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints Warnings with AVPlayerViewController embedded in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to set up an AVPlayerViewController completely through storyboards by embedding in a separate View Controller.

Steps:

1. Create Single View Application in Xcode.
2. Embed VC in navigation Controller.
3. Add toolbar at the bottom.(pinned to superView (Leading, Trailing, Bottom Layout Guide, Height(44)).
4. Add container View in parent View Controller.(pinned to superView (Leading, Trailing), Top Layout Guide, toolbar Top).
5. Remove the default View Controller that comes with container view.
6. Drag AV Player View Controller object from Object Library.
7. Connect embed segue from Container View to AV Player View Controller.

**NO CODE ADDED.**

This is what my **storyboard** looks like:

[image]

**View hierarchy:**

[image]

Everything runs fine:
**BUT THE PROBLEM IS:**
As soon as i run it I get these warnings in the debugger:

```
2015-09-30 12:58:35.904 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592bc70 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7f9325925590'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592bcf0 H:[UILabel:0x7f9325925590'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592bcf0 H:[UILabel:0x7f9325925590'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.905 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592bdd0 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7f9325929bb0'Slide your finger up to a...']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592be50 H:[UILabel:0x7f9325929bb0'Slide your finger up to a...']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592be50 H:[UILabel:0x7f9325929bb0'Slide your finger up to a...']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.906 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b5e0 V:|-(>=0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b660 V:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592af50 V:[UIView:0x7f932585e830(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325952c30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b660 V:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.907 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325829f90 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(15)-[UILabel:0x7f932347dc20'--:--'](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325839550 H:[UILabel:0x7f932347dc20'--:--']-(12)-[AVScrubber:0x7f93234a4350](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932585a2f0 AVScrubber:0x7f93234a4350.right == UILabel:0x7f932583a470'--:--'.left - 12>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b390 UILabel:0x7f932583a470'--:--'.right == AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325829f90 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(15)-[UILabel:0x7f932347dc20'--:--'](LTR)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.909 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325859740 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[UILabel:0x7f93234e53f0'Live Broadcast'](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bea0 UILabel:0x7f93234e53f0'Live Broadcast'.right <= AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9325859740 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[UILabel:0x7f93234e53f0'Live Broadcast'](LTR)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.910 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323520650 H:|-(0)-[UIActivityIndicatorView:0x7f93234e6ee0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f93234e6120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f93235206a0 H:[UIActivityIndicatorView:0x7f93234e6ee0]-(10)-[UILabel:0x7f93235203b0'Loading\U2026']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323520740 H:[UILabel:0x7f93235203b0'Loading\U2026']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f93234e6120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323521f90 H:|-(>=0)-[UIView:0x7f93234e6120]   (Names: '|':AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323510da0 UIView:0x7f93234e6120.centerX == AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bbc0 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bc10 AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.right <= AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f93235206a0 H:[UIActivityIndicatorView:0x7f93234e6ee0]-(10)-[UILabel:0x7f93235203b0'Loading…']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.912 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323521f90 H:|-(>=0)-[UIView:0x7f93234e6120]   (Names: '|':AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323510da0 UIView:0x7f93234e6120.centerX == AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bbc0 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bc10 AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.right <= AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323510da0 UIView:0x7f93234e6120.centerX == AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.centerX>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.912 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323521f90 H:|-(>=0)-[UIView:0x7f93234e6120]   (Names: '|':AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323510d10 H:[UIView:0x7f93234e6120]-(>=0)-|   (Names: '|':AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bbc0 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bc10 AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.right <= AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9323510d10 H:[UIView:0x7f93234e6120]-(>=0)-|   (Names: '|':AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-30 12:58:35.913 AVPlayerTest[9352:446772] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f93259513b0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba00 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592ba80 H:[UIView:0x7f932585fbc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7f9325860000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b770 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b7f0 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7f932585e990]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585e830 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b450 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f932585e830]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932592b4d0 H:[UIView:0x7f932585e830]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932582a040 H:|-(14)-[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f932585fbc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932586f490 AVButton:0x7f932585e480.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932580b340 AVButton:0x7f93234d1790.right == AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.left - 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932584c870 AVButton:0x7f93234d6540.right == UIView:0x7f932585fbc0.right - 14>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bbc0 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bc10 AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0.right <= AVButton:0x7f932585e480.left - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932594aa10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7f932585e310(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f932583bbc0 H:[AVButton:0x7f93258609b0]-(>=15)-[AVLoadingIndicatorView:0x7f93234e5fb0](LTR)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Sorry for the long Log, but all of it comes up at once so including it.
What am I missing? Auto layout is working great. Even on rotation. Why am I seeing these warnings?

Added [Sample Project](https://github.com/ishanhanda/AVPlayerTest)

**P.S.**: Using Xcode Version 7.0

**UPDATE**

Unchecking `Shows Playback Controls` on the `AVPlayerViewController` in the Attributes Inspector fixes it somehow and I see no warnings. But I need the controls. Seems more and more like a bug.

Comment: You said that "autolayout is working great". Did you run this code in all possible devices/screen sizes to see if it doesn't actually break for any of them? There is a "Preview" mode in Interface Builder.

Comment: Preview only shows the empty container view. On the simulator it works fine.

Comment: Added a sample project.

Comment: Mmh, no idea. Tried running your code. IB gives no autolayout warnings at edit time. Removing AVPlayer's vertical constraints results in a white screen (instead of black), and runtime warnings still appear. Last time I used movie players, auto layout or storyboards didn't exist yet...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and i am pretty sure it's a ios9 related one, since everything was working fine up to the upgrade.

Comment: @jalone Yeah. Unchecking `Shows Playback Controls` seems to take care of the warnings. I have added this to the question. Still not a fix though.

Comment: I have this problem too, sometimes on iPad panel doesn't contain playback controls because of this problem with constraints after going from full screen mode. Deployment target was 9.3, changed to 10, no problem with disappearing playback controls, but still have warnings.

Answer (score 28):

In fact, I think it's bug on Apple side.

I found a workaround : set showsPlaybackControls to YES after the AVPlayerViewController.player have been set.

I modify your sample with the following lines and no more Constraint error appears :

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(weak, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController * playerViewController;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
    AVPlayer * player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

    self.playerViewController.player = player;
    self.playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AVPlayerSegue"]) {
        self.playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}


@end
```

Please note that the file `test.mp4` have been added to the project.

Comment: I'm not so sure about using the `showsPlaybackControls` property. The docs say "Do not use this property to change the visibility of the playback controls while the player view controller is onscreen, because doing so creates or destroys UI elements." And also this does't work if i don't provide a resource URL to the AVPlayer. What if I have to dynamically load an AVAsset at runtime? In that case i will have to setup the UI before anything else. According to your answer, providing a dummy file may be the solution for the time being. This does help a little.

Comment: Did not help me (the exception still visible) on iPhone6s Plus, iOS9.2.

Comment: didn't work for me neither, i get a number of contraints warning, all horizontally, as soon as I tap on the fullscreen button. iOS 9.3.

Comment: If you're creating `AVPlayerViewController` from code, don't forget to set `showsPlaybackControls` to `NO` immediately after creation. This did the trick for me (comined with above snippet).

Comment: Setting showsPlaybackControls to false during init and true when the media is ready to play did solve the layout constraint warning. However, it also causes the AVPlayer to fail to deinit when AVPlayerViewController goes away.

Comment: @gbitaudeau I have checked the above its not working on iOS 10 & xcode 8.2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @PavanMore I just try it on my iPhone 6 with iOs 10.3.2 with Xcode 8.2 and it's working very well without any warning. Did you notice that you need a file "test.mp4" ?

Comment: @gbitaudeau Yes I have added video file. I am checking on the xcode 8.2 and iOS 10.2 with iPhone 6 simulator. What I have noticed once I tap on video play button and make full screen then it throws warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your code and took a look at it. You are not doing anything wrong. The fact that you can uncheck "Shows Playback Control" seems to indicate that the problem lies with the AVKit framework. I've even tried setting the value to false in the XIB file and then calling `[self setShowsPlaybackControls:YES];` after `viewDidAppear:` with the same results. This is most definitely an Apple bug and you should raise a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I allow on iPhones only the portrait mode while I want the `AVPlayerViewController` to have all directions.

In `AppDelegate` I have code that looks like this:

```
public func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is AVPlayerViewController {

        return .All
    }
    return Device.current.contains(.iPhone) ? [.Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown] : .All
}
```

When `AVPlayerViewController` is presented modally, rotated to landscape and dismissed I'll get a very smiler error stack that some constraints broke.

To workaround I added this code to my `RootViewController`, which also presents any instance of `AVPlayerViewController` in my application:

```
public override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

    if let playerViewController = self.presentedViewController as? AVPlayerViewController {

        playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    }

    super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
}
```

Basically I'm catching the moment when the user taps on the dismiss button and use the workaround found in original question post.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this bug is still present in ios 10.1.
Anyway, I have observed that if I present the view controller with the seekTime set to 0, the bug is not present.
So, my solution was to pause the player, retain the currentTime, seek the player to 0, present the controller and on the completion do the following: seek to the retained time and play again.

```
AVPlayer *player;
AVPlayerViewController *avPlayerController;
CMTime currentTime;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.bounds;
    avPlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    avPlayerController.player = player;

}

- (IBAction)fullScreen:(id)sender {
    [player pause];
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    [player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1)];

    [self presentViewController:avPlayerController animated:YES completion:^{
        [avPlayerController.player seekToTime:currentTime];
        [avPlayerController.player play];
    }];
}
```

Comment: After two days fighting with this bug, yours is the only workaround that works for me (iOS 10.3).

Answer (score 0):

I realised this is happening when you try to present the same AVPlayerViewController instance (using a strong reference property) the second, third...etc time and the player controls are not reset (i.e. the progress is not at the beginning).

[image: Progress bar not in 0:00]

Actually, if you are facing the same scenario, before tapping "Done" try to drag the progress bar to the beginning and present AVPlayerViewController again. Then the auto layout issue should disappear!

So basically the Autolayout issue (Apple issue by the way) can be fixed if you reset the controls before dismissing AVPlayerViewController. But, what if you want to present the same video? In my case I want to keep the reference to AVPlayerItem:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
```

But I don't want this crash to happen:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184035900 0x1836a3f80 0x18a254958 0x18a23fc14 0x100054a2c 0x188d5fe50 0x188d5fdcc 0x188d47a88 0x188d5f6e4 0x188d18294 0x188d58820 0x188d57e1c 0x188d284cc 0x188d26794 0x183fecefc 0x183fec990 0x183fea690 0x183f19680 0x185428088 0x188d90d90 0x1000eea78 0x183aba8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So my workaround was to create a copy of the AVPLayerItem every time I push AVPlayerViewController. With that way, the crash and auto layout issue are gone. However, the video is reset every time you push the player.

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem.copy];
```

Comment: looks like a promising solution

Answer (score -1):

This warning is saying that you have used one constraint extra that didn't need to be use.

**ToolBarHeight** by default is **44** for all iphone devices here you have used height constraint for `UIToolBar`. So the Toolbar Height Constraint is extra here , Remove this constraint the warning will be remove automatically

Comment: I understand what the warning means. But it is not due to the toolbar height constraint. Although the default height is 44, it can be increased or decreased if required. So adding a constraint on it should not be a problem. Moreover, I don't see the toolbar anywhere in the logged conflicting constraints. But still I tried removing the constraint and it doesn't help. I get the exact same warnings.