# YTPlayer ios helper - iOS 9 constraint issue

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayerview

YTPlayer iOS helper shows the below warnings when I try to run the video in fullscreen. I don't see these warnings in iOS8.

**Update** - This seems to be iOS 9 bug from apple where fullscreen video played from UIWebView on iOS 9 device will show these warnings in the console.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51ea86cd0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa670 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7fa51ea4d030'Slide your finger down to...']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa6c0 H:[UILabel:0x7fa51ea4d030'Slide your finger down to...']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51def9e10 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51def9e60 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa110 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa160 H:[UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51ea8d1a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140(0)]>"
```

)

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51ea86cd0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600.width == _UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa770 H:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x7fa51ea48b40'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa7f0 H:[UILabel:0x7fa51ea48b40'Hi-Speed Scrubbing']-(14)-|   (Names: '|':_UIBackdropContentView:0x7fa51e92b600 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51def9e10 H:|-(0)-[_UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51def9e60 H:[_UIBackdropView:0x7fa51e9187f0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa110 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70]   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51defa160 H:[UIView:0x7fa51dddfd70]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51ea8d1a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVAlphaUpdatingView:0x7fa51dad7140(0)]>"
```

)

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Not yet. Filed bug to apple. Not sure if we can do anything about it.

Comment: [rdar://24298515](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4964336976003072)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints Warnings with AVPlayerViewController embedded in storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860362/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-warnings-with-avplayerviewcontrolle)